# Bot detection ideas

Tags: php, detection, bots

I am looking for bot detection ideas. I don't mind bots crawling my site, that's cool, the problem is when they start posting stuff. I recently had to erase 400 accounts because of a bad boy like that. So what are my options?

Captchas aren't really an option, we don't live in 1990 anymore. Another method I found that seemed interesting was a db of known bots, as well as searching the user agent string for bot spider crawler etc, which seemed pretty promising, but then there's that hardcoding names part which I don't like for obvious reasons and I guess that wouldn't work as well.

I'm looking for something that doesn't need to be updated and will pretty much work until the end of time. My idea was to create a check-for-bot method which would be called on all posts (POST requests that insert into a table) and record the time of the post and the IP of the user/bot and whenever a record exists its time of creation will be compared to current time and stuff like that, but that would fail too because there are networks that use the same IP and may cause an issue there, especially with wifi, you know how it is nowadays.

Does anyone have any idea, possibly similar to mine, or even better? I really need to stop those bots from keeping posting stuff to my site but I need it to be a neat way too.

Thank you for your time reading this, even if you cannot help me!

Comment: see http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/3799/1253

Comment: Google, Microsoft, etc. seem to think otherwise :-)

Comment: I recommend asking on [security.se] instead of here. Please give us a bit more information about your application: what kind of functionality does it offer that you want to prevent bots from using?

Comment: @Gilles Thank you for the note. I will ask that there and I will provide more information!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding an input field that's displayed off the screen so that a normal user won't ever fill it out. Most bots will try and fill in every field that seems relevant so if that hidden field is filled in, just ignore the post.

Comment: That's a very interesting suggestion, I will apply that. However I feel kind of skeptical about it, just a feeling. Thanks! :P

Comment: It definitely wouldn't stop all bots trying but it would filter out some of them for sure. Try it for sure though!

Good luck! :)